# How to simulate the up key using the keyboard module in python?

Tags: python, selenium, keyboard, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the keyboard module on python to input text using Selenium. I am trying to simulate `shift + up_key` to highlight and delete text but I am not familiar with the keycodes in python. I am using macOS to simulate the keypresses.

```
    if current_url == TARGET_URL:
        print("success!")
    else:
        #up_key not being a valid keystroke
        keyboard.send("shift+up_key")
        keyboard.send("delete")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a WebElement, let's say **element**, you can do following :

```
element.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)
```

or

```
element.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_SHIFT, Keys.ARROW_UP)
```

**import would be :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```